# Cannot Add Background Image in PHP

Tags: php, html, css

I have used following code to add a background image to my PHP file.

```
body {
 background-image:url('background.png');
 background-color: #F0F8FF;
}
```

But I can see the color only changed not the image. Can someone help me to solve this? Does this due to the image resolutions? I exported the image from microsoft powerpoint. Do I need to consider that as well? Are there any method to find whether the issue with my code or my picture.
I have pasted my whole code.

```
<?php   
 session_start();  
 ?>  
 <!DOCTYPE html>  
 <html>  
      <head>  
           <title>Library Management System</title>  
                      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />  
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>   
      </head>  
      <body>  
           <br />  
           <div class="container" style="width:700px;">  
                <h3 align="center">Management System</h3><br />  
                <br />  
                <br />  
                <br />  
                <br />  
                <br />  
                <?php  
                if(isset($_SESSION['username']))  
                {  
                 
   
               
                 ?>  
                <div align="center">  
                     <h1>Welcome to Dialog G-Tech Library</h1><br />
                     <div class="bar" align="center">
                     <a href="#" id="logout">Logout</a>
                      </div>  
                </div>  
   
                <?php      
                 
                }  
                else  
                {  
                ?>  
                 <div id="loginModal"  role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
   <!-- Modal content-->
           <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                     <h4 class="modal-title">Login</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                     <label>Username</label>
                     <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control" />
                     <br />
                     <label>Password</label>
                     <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" />
                     <br />
                     <button type="button" name="login_button" id="login_button" class="btn btn-warning">Login</button>
                </div>
           </div>
      </div>
 </div> 
                <?php  
                }  
                ?>  
           </div>  
           <br />  
      </body>



  <style type="text/css">
   .bar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #87CEEB;
}

.bar a {
  float: left;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.bar a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}


body {
 background-image:url('background.png');
 background-color: #F0F8FF;
} 



   </style>
 </html>  
 <div id="loginModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">  
      <div class="modal-dialog">  
   <!-- Modal content-->  
           <div class="modal-content">  
                <div class="modal-header">  
                     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>  
                     <h4 class="modal-title">Login</h4>  
                </div>  
                <div class="modal-body">  
                     <label>Username</label>  
                     <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control" />  
                     <br />  
                     <label>Password</label>  
                     <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" />  
                     <br />  
                     <button type="button" name="login_button" id="login_button" class="btn btn-warning">Login</button>  
                </div>  
           </div>  
      </div>  
 </div>
```

Comment: does ```background-image``` not work if you remove ```background-color```? Because I think ```background-color``` is overlapping your image that is why you can't see it.

Comment: checked that as well. Then color will remove only.

Comment: The path to the image needs to be relative to the CSS file or in your case, the current page URL

Comment: Check with the browser's developer-tools if the background is requested from and delivered by the webserver. Maybe it is not available at this webserver's location?

Comment: @Phil I tried this way as well. background-image:url('http://10.10.10.10/system/background.png');

Comment: adding background image is not related to php
you should just make dynamic this background path using php.

Comment: @ArifulIslam can you help me with an Answer?

Comment: Where is that image actually stored? What is its full URL? Try using that (https://.....) as an experiment.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the cache won’t realize that changes have been made to your website. A **hard refresh** is a way of clearing the browser’s cache for a specific page, to force it to load the most recent version of a page. Sometimes, when changes are made to the website, they don’t register immediately due to caching. A hard refresh will usually fix this, though occasionally completely clearing the cache is necessary.

Right Click on the refresh button and click on **`Empty Cache and Hard Reload`** and check its working or not

[image]